# Increase the line border of chartView aChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I need to increase the border width of the chart (At the x- axis, parallel line opposite to x-axis, y-axis, and line parallel to y-axis ). How can I go about it? There doesn't seem to be any direct function for that.[image: This is the graph that I have implemented]

Comment: You mean padding? try `renderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);` and so

Comment: no padding. I mean the border of axeses